# ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm looking for how to use `ObjectInputStream` for a university project. 
I found a lot of things but I don't know why I can't succeed with it. Worst, I have more and more warnings.

Here are my three classes:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>
{
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private int numTel;
private static int nbContacts;
private int numContact;

public Contact(String nom, int tel) //Constructeur nom et numero
{
    System.out.println(this.numTel);
    this.numTel = tel;
    System.out.println(this.numTel);
    this.nom = nom;
    this.numContact=++nbContacts;
}

public Contact(String nom)  //Constructeur Nom
{
    this.nom = nom;
    this.numContact=++nbContacts;
}

public Contact(String nom, String prenom, int tel) //Constructeur Nom, prenom, numero
{
    this.numTel = tel;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.numContact=++nbContacts;
}

public String getNom()
{
    return this.nom;
}

public String getPrenom()
{
    return this.prenom;
}

public int getTelephone()
{
    return this.numTel;
}

public int getNumContact()
{
    return this.numContact;
}

public void setNom(String nom)
{
    this.nom = nom;
}

public void setNumTelephone(int num)
{ 
    this.numTel = num;
}

public boolean equals(Contact contact)
{
    if(!this.nom.equals(contact.getNom()))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(this.numTel!=contact.getTelephone())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public int compareTo(Contact contact)
{
    return (Integer.valueOf(this.nom) - Integer.valueOf(contact.getNom()));
}   
public String toString()
{
    String s = this.numContact + ") ";
    s+= String.format ( "%-10s", "NOM : ")  + this.nom;
    if(this.prenom != null)
    {
        s+=" | " + String.format ( "%-10s", "PRENOM : " )  + this.prenom ;
    }
    if(this.numTel != 0)
    {
        s+=  " : " + this.numTel;
    }           
    s += "\n";      
    System.out.println(this.nom);
    return s;
}
}
```

next

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections; 
public class Repertoire 
{
    private ArrayList<Contact>alContact;

public Repertoire()
{
    alContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    this.getData();
}

public String toString() 
{
    String s = "";
    for ( int cpt = 0; cpt < alContact.size(); cpt++ )
    {
        s += alContact.get(cpt).toString() + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}

public void addContact(String nom, int tel) //Constructeur nom et numero
{
    alContact.add(new Contact(nom, tel));
    this.sauvegarder();
}

public void addContact(String nom)  //Constructeur Nom
{
    alContact.add(new Contact(nom));
    this.sauvegarder();
}

public void addContact(String nom, String prenom, int tel) //Constructeur Nom, prenom, numero
{
    alContact.add(new Contact(nom, prenom, tel));
    this.sauvegarder();
}


// Permet d'enregistrer dans un fichier .dat les éléments du répertoire 
private void sauvegarder()
{
    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream ( new FileOutputStream ("Rep.txt") );
        out.writeObject ( alContact );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {}
}

public void getData() 
{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try 
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream("~/Rep.txt");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        alContact = (ArrayList) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Bordel");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Gros Bordel");
    }
}
// Permet de recuperer les donnée dans un fichier txt
private boolean charger()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Dedans");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream ( new FileInputStream ("Rep.txt"));
        System.out.println("Dedans");
        alContact = (ArrayList<Contact>) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("Dedans");
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    {
        System.out.println("Pas de fichier");   
        return false;
    }

    Collections.sort (alContact);
    return true;
}
```

}

And just a Test

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int tel;
        Repertoire rep = new Repertoire();
        /*System.out.println("Entrez le numero");
        tel = Clavier.lire_int();
        rep.addContact("José", tel);
        */System.out.println(rep);
    }
}
```

This program is a phone index. 
I try to save index into a .txt/.dat but when I can't put it into the program. 
I hope it's understandable.

Comment: You need to tell us what's wrong rather than just that it doesn't work - and you've posted a *lot* of code here. It would be better to try to write a *very small* test program which *just* serializes a really simple class and deserializes it. Aside from anything else, that will make it much easier to focus on one problem at a time - you won't be distracted by unrelated problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Contact` class must implement `Serializable` in order to be serializable to save/read to/from `InputObjectStream`/`OutputObjectStream`.

From [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) documentation:

> Classes control how they are serialized by implementing either the java.io.Serializable or java.io.Externalizable interfaces
>
> Implementing the Serializable interface allows object serialization to save and restore the entire state of the object and it allows classes to evolve between the time the stream is written and the time it is read. It automatically traverses references between objects, saving and restoring entire graphs.

Note that when you run the `Repertoire#getData` in your program and your file is empty, you won't load any data at all. So, it would be better to first save some data in it. You can do this to add some data:

```
public void setStartData() {
    Contact contact = new Contact("Luiggi", "Mendoza", 12345);
    List<Contact> lstContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    lstContact.add(contact);
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Rep.txt"));
        out.writeObject(lstContact);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while saving data.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Additional advices:

- `static` fields won't be serialized when saving data on file.
- The data would be serialized in the file, so even if you treat it as a text file, its contents won't be like in human readable text (at least that you speak Java Serializable language).
- Every attribute in your `Serializable` class should be serializable as well. This means, if you have an object instance inside it, its class **must** implement the `Serializable` interface.
- You can omit an attribute from serialization by adding the `transient` modifier.
- **IMPORTANT**: If you save the data, change the class definition and try to load the data, you would get an error. Make sure your class has **the same structure** when serializing/deserializing it. Looks like you were running on this issue for the last errors.

Comment: I already try it; but i'm not sure, i just add
import java.io.*;
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>, Serializable
 At top

Comment: @user2220578 maybe your file is empty, so since it doesn't read anything at all you can't load anything. Try saving some data first.

Comment: @user2220578 note that static attributes won't be serialized, so it won't be saved when deserializing the objects.

Comment: I already tried with just a name and a number, it's realy short, but i think it's enough

Comment: I just try with your code for put somme data, but when i try to load it after, I go into 
catch (IOException ex)

Comment: @user2220578 make sure you're reading from the same file. You're just blindly copying/pasting code instead of read it and adapt it to your needs i.e. I used `new FileOutputStream("Rep.txt")` to save the data and you use `new FileInputStream("~/Rep.txt")` to read it =\. Don't expect that people will give you the right exact code you need.

Comment: @user2220578 also, **please** read the description of the error and try to understand its meaning instead of saying *it doesn't work, please help*.

Comment: No, i correct the FileInputStream, ~/Rep.txt was just for a test so i put Rep.txt

Comment: @user2220578 delete the file, run the code to save the data in it and then the code to load the data.

Comment: Sorry @luiggi I swear I try since more than 5 hours to solve it alone, but I don't know why it don't load it and it go into catch (IOException ex)

Comment: @user2220578 ok, then edit your question and **add** the stacktrace of this IOException (note: **do not delete nor change** none of the actual content of your question).

Comment: You where right, when i deleted file and recreat it it's working fine
thank you

Comment: @user2220578 please mark the post as answer by clicking on the check below the points. Also, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the way you have overridden your `equals` method in `Contact` class.

Its parameter should be of `Object` type . It should be like this

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if ( ! (obj instanceof Contact))
    return false;
    Contact contact = (Contact) obj;
    if(!this.nom.equals(contact.getNom()))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(this.numTel!=contact.getTelephone())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also make your `Contact` class `Serialzable` by implementing `Serializable` interface while defining the `Contact` class.

Your sauvegarder method should be like this:

```
private void sauvegarder()
{
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream ( new FileOutputStream ("Rep.txt") );
        out.writeObject ( alContact );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {}
    finally
    {
      if(out!=null)
      {
        try
        {
           out.close();//close the outputstream
        }catch(Exception ex){}
      }
    }
}
```

And your `getData` method should be like this:

```
public void getData() 
{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try 
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Rep.txt");//Why using ~/Rep.txt instead of Rep.txt?
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        alContact = (ArrayList<Contact>) in.readObject();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Bordel");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Gros Bordel");
    }
    finally
    {
      if(in != null)
      {
        try
        {
           in.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
      }
    }
}
```

And you are reading data from the file which does'nt exist because you haven't written anything till now so for demo you can change your constructor `Repertoire` in this way:

```
public Repertoire()
{
    alContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    addContact("John",879999);
    addContact("Micky",4333);
    sauvegarder();
    this.getData();
}
```

And change your `Contact` class declaration as follows:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>,java.io.Serializable
```

Comment: I use ~/Rep.txt because of I thought there was a probleme with access way so I try an other one. 
There is a probleme with out, javac tell me that cannot find symbol out.

Comment: @user2220578 I have rectified that error of `cannot find symbol out`

Comment: yes, I just saw it thanks. But i still have same problem, when I try to load it it go into catch(IOException ex), do you know why ?

Comment: @user2220578 Did you update the `Repertoire` constructor? And in which method now are you getting error?

Comment: thank you for help, I was just needed to delet rep.txt and recreat it. Tank you